# Samsung galaxy S3 Soft/Hard bricked

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, unbricking

So, I used Mobile ODIN to flash my stock ROM (since PC ODIN fails) and It done something. When I came back to it, the screen was stuck on this:
[image: Sigh]

and stays that way. Recovery Mode is dead (I cant boot into it) and my main OS has joined it. ODIN PC Does not recognise the device (but that is not new)

I have tried Plugging it into my PC, to get this:[image]

So, can anyone help (I have tried re-installing the samsung drivers, which did not help. I did accidently cancel the 'installing device', so it may be a case of somehow restarting that.)

Comment: You have the International S3, correct, and not a US-based S3?

Comment: @RMarkwald Yes. If it matters, it is also unlocked (sim-wise)

Comment: Is Download Mode still accessible?

Comment: @MatthewRead Yes, but the device is not recognised. Do you think I can get away with taking it into game, and saying the +1 on the counter was a destructive trojan that robs data then kills the OS?

Comment: Probably not.  Anything that they do should be doable by you ... Samsung devices are quite hard to hard-brick.  I would suggest installing Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine, and enabling USB pass-through for your device, and then you can see if Heimdall will recognize it in Ubuntu.

Comment: @MatthewRead Good job I have Linux mint, eh? I'll have to look at it tomorrow, seeing how said Linux device is currently going through its monthly updates.

Comment: Ah yes, if you have another install/box that's best to try first. Good luck.

Comment: @MatthewRead Thanks :) also, since Linux mint is still debian-based, I doubt problems will incur.

Comment: @MatthewRead device not detected in heimdall (UI).Ubuntu and Mint show no device. Any ideas??

Comment: @MatthewRead or do I need to load the ROM in heimdall first? its heimdall 1.4, installed via apt.

Comment: That's not good.  Is the device in the output of `lsusb`?  Try following this https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/UDEV

Comment: @MatthewRead Device is **not** included in 'lsusb' and fixing the UDEV issues does nothing to help.

Comment: That's definitely not good.  Points to either a hardware issue or the device firmware being very very borked.

Comment: @MatthewRead Probably firmware- the last logs and kernel logs I pulled (I constantly have adb pull them- I forgot!) It seems a trojan used screen overlays to spoof a OS update to Get into download mode, and somehow flash itself. Yes, download mode, not recovery.

Comment: @MatthewRead With that in mind, do you think it will fall under warranty, considering a trojan flashed itself (which did trigger the Ol' Knox counter)?

Comment: Yes you could definitely argue that!